# OVH JAVA API using Get request with parameters

Tags: java, rest, api, http, ovh

am trying to create a web interface to interact with OVH's telephony API [ovh telephony api](https://api.ovh.com/console/#/telephony)  using the official JAVA wrapper [OVH java wrapper](https://github.com/ovh/java-ovh).

I am trying to use a GET endpoint with parameters. this is the endpoint:

> GET /telephony/{billingAccount}/line/{serviceName}/statistics
>
> Parameters:
>
> ```
>           timeframe: string;  
>
>           type : string
> ```

This is how I am doing the call:

```
api.get("/telephony/{myBuildingAccount}/line/{myServiceNumber}/statistics", "timeframe=daily&type=maxDelay", true);
```

But I am getting an error 400 bad signature.

Could someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API of the java wrapper specifies that the `api.get` method receives as the second parameter (in the three parameters version of `api.get`) the GET body; but you are passing a string containing the URL parameters:

```
api.get("/telephony/{ACCT}/line/{NUM}/statistics", "timeframe=daily&type=maxDelay", true);
```

Since the request you need does not require a body and does require the parameters in the URL, you need to use the following invocation:

```
api.get("/telephony/{ACCT}/line/{NUM}/statistics?timeframe=daily&type=maxDelay", true);
```

Pay attention that `{ACCT}` and `{NUM}` must be replaced by the actual account and service number values in that first string. Also, notice the parameters are appended directly into the string URL.

Hope this helps.